# Avoid running function more than once

Tags: php

Hi what would be a better way to write the following code so `myScript()` isn't executed several times?

```
<?php

function myScript($myVar){
  //some code
  return $anotherVar;
}

$data = myScript("some input");
echo $data.$data.$data;
```

Comment: I don't see it used even once...what do you mean?

Comment: @Rasclatt, sorry, my mistake. Edited!

Comment: If you mean `$data`, you only executed it once to the `$data` variable.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize it executes when it's set as a variable. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, you have set it once, then returned a value to `$data`, then you just repeated data. It's not the same as doing `myScript("some input").myScript("some input").myScript("some input");`

Comment: @user1661677, What you want? Running function more than one or use the return value more than one.

Comment: Why you want to restrict your function to executed more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$data** variable just storing the output its not execute several time when you echo the variable .

Comment: this must be comment not an answer!

Comment: Its my bad luck today, i can't help any person properly. Everywhere i got the same result. My fate for today.

Answer (score 0):

In your script the function execute only once. you use the return value more and more.

> The function never run alone, it is you who can call for a function to
>   run.

```
function myScript($myVar){
  return $anotherVar; //5
}

$data = myScript("some input");
echo $data.$data.$data; //555
```

You can also call this function multiple time if you want different values for different parameter like:

```
function myScript($myVar){
  return $myVar * $myVar;
}

$data1 = myScript(3);
$data2 = myScript(4);
$data3 = myScript(5);
echo $data1." - ".$data2." - ".$data3; //9 - 16 - 25
```